# How to fade in image objects once loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that allows users to move objects around. However, once the objects load I want them to all fade in. How can I do this? Here is my javascript. Here is the website so that you can see it. http://prototypesyndicate.com/kimmel/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
             * idx:
             * index of photo that is currently hold
             * idxLarge:
             * index of photo that is currently on full mode
             * mouseup:
             * flag to use on the mouseup and mousedown events,
             * to help preventing the browser default selection of elements
             */
            var idx,idxLarge    = -1;
            var mouseup         = false;

            /**
             * for now we hardcode the values of our thumb containers
             */
            var photoW          = 184;
            var photoH          = 205;

            /**
             * the photos and options container
             */
            var $container      = $('#pd_container');

            var $options        = $('#pd_options_bar');

            var photosSize      = $container.find('.pd_photo').length;

            /**
             * navigation current step
             */
            var navPage         = 0;
            /**
             * spreads the photos on the table..
             */

            var ie              = false;
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                ie = true;
            }

            start();

            function start(){
                $('#pd_loading').show();

                var tableW          = $container.width();
                var tableH          = $container.height();

                var horizontalMax   = tableW - photoW;
                var verticalMax     = tableH - photoH;

                $('<img />').attr('src','images/paperball.png');
                /**
                * display all the photos on the desk, with a random rotation,
                 * and also make them draggable.
                 * on mouse down, we want the photo to enlarge in a few pixels,
                 * and to rotate 0 degrees
                 */
                var cntPhotos = 0;
                $container.find('.pd_photo').each(function(i){
                    var $photo  = $(this);
                    $('<img />').load(function(){
                        ++cntPhotos;
                        var $image  = $(this);

                    var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*201)-100;//*41
                    var maxzidx = parseInt(findHighestZIndex()) + 1;
                    var param   = {
                        'top'       : Math.floor(Math.random()*verticalMax) +'px',       
                        'left'      : Math.floor(Math.random()*horizontalMax) +'px',
                            'z-index'   : maxzidx
                    };

                        $photo.css(param);
                        if(!ie)
                            $photo.transform({'rotate'  : r + 'deg'});
                        $photo.show();  
                        if(cntPhotos == photosSize){
                bindEvents();
                            $('#pd_loading').hide();
                        }
                    }).attr('src',$photo.find('img').attr('src'));  
                }); 
            }

            /**
             * grab a photo
             */
            function mouseDown($photo){
                mouseup     = true;
                idx         = $photo.index() + 1;
                var maxzidx = parseInt(findHighestZIndex()) + 1;
                $photo.css('z-index',maxzidx);
                if(ie)
                var param = {
                    'width'     : '+=40px',
                    'height'    : '+=40px'
                };
                else
                var param = {
                    'width'     : '+=40px',
                    'height'    : '+=40px',
                    'rotate'    : '0deg',
                    //'shadow'  : '5px 5px 15px #222'
                };
                $photo.stop(true,true).animate(param,100).find('img').stop(true,true).animate({
                    'width'     : '+=40px',
                    'height'    : '+=40px'
                },100);
            }

            /**
             * we do the mouseup on the document to prevent the
             * case when we release the mouse outside of a photo.
             * also, we want the photo to get smaller again,
             * rotate some random degrees, and also move it some pixels
             */
            $(document).bind('mouseup',function(e){
                if(mouseup){
                    mouseup     = false;
                    var $photo  = $container.find('.pd_photo:nth-child('+idx+')');
                    var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*101)-50;
                    var $photoT = parseFloat($photo.css('top'),10);
                    var $photoL = parseFloat($photo.css('left'),10);
                    var newTop  = $photoT + r;
                    var newLeft = $photoL + r;
                    if(ie)
                    var param = {
                        'width'     : '-=40px',
                        'height'    : '-=40px',
                        'top'       : newTop + 'px', 
                        'left'      : newLeft + 'px'
                    };
                    else
                    var param = {
                        'width'     : '-=40px',
                        'height'    : '-=40px',
                        'top'       : newTop + 'px',
                        'left'      : newLeft + 'px',
                        //'rotate'  : r+'deg',
                        //'shadow'  : '0 0 5px #000'
                    };
                    $photo.stop(true,true).animate(param,200).find('img').stop(true,true).animate({
                        'width' : '-=40px',
                        'height': '-=40px'
                    },200);
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            /**
             * removes the photo element from the DOM,
             * after showing the paper image..
             */
            $container.find('.delete').bind('click',function(){
                var $photo          = $(this).parent();
                var $photoT         = parseFloat($photo.css('top'),10);
                var $photoL         = parseFloat($photo.css('left'),10);
                var $photoZIndex    = $photo.css('z-index');
                var $trash = $('<div />',{
                    'className' : 'pd_paperball',
                    'style'     : 'top:' + parseInt($photoT + photoH/2) + 'px;left:' + parseInt($photoL + photoW/2) +'px;width:0px;height:0px;z-index:' + $photoZIndex
                }).appendTo($container);

                $trash.animate({
                    'width' : photoW + 'px',
                    'height': photoH + 'px',
                    'top'   : $photoT + 'px',
                    'left'  : $photoL + 'px'
                },100,function(){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $this.remove();
                    },800);
                });
                $photo.animate({
                    'width' : '0px',
                    'height': '0px',
                    'top'   : $photoT + photoH/2 + 'px',
                    'left'  : $photoL + photoW/2 +'px'
                },200,function(){
                    --photosSize;
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });

            function stack(){
                navPage         = 0;
                var cnt_photos  = 0;
                var windowsW        = $(window).width();
                var windowsH        = $(window).height();
                $container.find('.pd_photo').each(function(i){
                    var $photo  = $(this);
                    $photo.css('z-index',parseInt(findHighestZIndex()) + 1000 + i)
                    .stop(true)
                    .animate({
                        'top'   : parseInt((windowsH-100)/2 - photoH/2) + 'px',
                        'left'  : parseInt((windowsW-100)/2 - photoW/2) + 'px'
                    },800,function(){
                        $options.find('.backdesk').show();
                        var $photo = $(this);
                        ++cnt_photos;
                        var $nav    = $('<a class="pd_next_photo" style="display:none;"></a>');
                        $nav.bind('click',function(){
                            navigate();
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                        $photo.prepend($nav);
                        $photo.draggable('destroy')
                        .find('.delete')
                        .hide()
                        .andSelf()
                        .find('.pd_hold')
                        .unbind('mousedown')
                        .bind('mousedown',function(){return false;});

                        $photo.unbind('mouseenter')
                        .bind('mouseenter',function(){
                            $nav.show();
                        })
                        .unbind('mouseleave')
                        .bind('mouseleave',function(){
                            $nav.hide();
                        });
                        $options.find('.shuffle,.viewall').unbind('click');
                        if(cnt_photos == photosSize)
                            enlarge(findElementHighestZIndex());
                    });
                });
            }

            function enlarge($photo){
                var windowsW        = $(window).width();
                var windowsH        = $(window).height();
                if(ie)
                var param = {
                    'width' : '+=200px',
                    'height': '+=200px',
                    'top'   : parseInt((windowsH-100)/2 - (photoH+200)/2) + 'px', 
                    'left'  : parseInt((windowsW-100)/2 - (photoW+200)/2) + 'px'
                };
                else
                var param = {
                    'width' : '+=200px',
                    'height': '+=200px',
                    'top'   : parseInt((windowsH-100)/2 - (photoH+200)/2) + 'px',
                    'left'  : parseInt((windowsW-100)/2 - (photoW+200)/2) + 'px',
                    'rotate': '0deg',
                    'shadow': '5px 5px 15px #222'
                };
                $photo.animate(param,500,function(){
                    idxLarge = $(this).index();
                }).find('img').animate({
                    'width' : '+=200px',
                    'height': '+=200px'
                },500);
            }

            /**
             * back to desk
             */
            function disperse(){
                var windowsW        = $(window).width();
                var windowsH        = $(window).height();

                $container.find('.pd_photo').each(function(i){
                    var $photo      = $(this);
                    //if it is the current large photo:
                    if($photo.index() == idxLarge){
                        if(ie)
                        var param = {
                            'top'       : parseInt((windowsH-100)/2 - photoH/2) + 'px', 
                            'left'      : parseInt((windowsW-100)/2 - photoW/2) + 'px',
                            'width'     : '170px',
                            'height'    : '170px'
                        };
                        else
                        var param = {
                            'top'       : parseInt((windowsH-100)/2 - photoH/2) + 'px', 
                            'left'      : parseInt((windowsW-100)/2 - photoW/2) + 'px',
                            'width'     : '170px',
                            'height'    : '170px',
                            'shadow'    : '1px 1px 5px #555'
                        };
                        $photo.stop(true).animate(param,500, function(){
                            shuffle();
                            $options.find('.viewall').show();
                        }).find('img').animate({
                            'width'     : '170px',
                            'height'    : '170px'
                        },500);
                    }
                });
                $container.find('.pd_next_photo').remove();
                bindEvents();
            }

            function bindEvents(){
                $options.find('.shuffle').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
                    if(photosSize == 0) return;
                    shuffle();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }).andSelf().find('.viewall').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if(photosSize == 0) return;
                    stack();
                    $this.hide();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }).andSelf().find('.backdesk').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if(photosSize == 0) return;
                    disperse();
                    $this.hide();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                $container.find('.pd_photo').each(function(i){
                    var $photo = $(this);
                    $photo.draggable({
                        containment : '#pd_container'
                    }).find('.delete')
                    .show()
                }).find('.pd_hold').unbind('mousedown').bind('mousedown',function(e){
                    var $photo  = $(this).parent();
                    mouseDown($photo);
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            }

            function navigate(){
                if(photosSize == 0) return;

                var tableW          = $container.width();
                var tableH          = $container.height();

                var horizontalMax   = tableW - photoW;
                var verticalMax     = tableH - photoH;

                var $photo          = $container.find('.pd_photo:nth-child('+parseInt(idxLarge+1)+')');
                var r               = Math.floor(Math.random()*201)-100;//*41
                if(ie)
                var param = {
                    'top'       : Math.floor(Math.random()*verticalMax) +'px',       
                    'left'      : Math.floor(Math.random()*horizontalMax) +'px',
                    'width'     : '170px',
                    'height'    : '170px'
                };
                else
                var param = {
                    'top'       : Math.floor(Math.random()*verticalMax) +'px',
                    'left'      : Math.floor(Math.random()*horizontalMax) +'px',
                    'width'     : '170px',
                    'height'    : '170px',
                    'rotate'    : r+'deg',
                    'shadow'    : '1px 1px 5px #555'
                };
                $photo.stop(true).animate(param,500,function(){
                    ++navPage;
                    var $photo = $(this);

                    $container.append($photo.css('z-index',1));
                    if(navPage < photosSize)
                        enlarge(findElementHighestZIndex());
                    else{ //last one
                        $options.find('.backdesk').hide();
                        $options.find('.viewall').show();
                        bindEvents();
                    }
                }).find('img').animate({
                    'width'     : '170px',
                    'height'    : '170px'
                },500);
            }

            function shuffle(){
                var tableW          = $container.width();
                var tableH          = $container.height();

                var horizontalMax   = tableW - photoW;
                var verticalMax     = tableH - photoH;
                $container.find('.pd_photo').each(function(i){
                    var $photo = $(this);
                    var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*301)-100;//*41
                    if(ie)
                    var param = {
                        'top'       : Math.floor(Math.random()*verticalMax) +'px',       
                        'left'      : Math.floor(Math.random()*horizontalMax) +'px'
                    };
                    else
                    var param = {
                        'top'       : Math.floor(Math.random()*verticalMax) +'px',
                        'left'      : Math.floor(Math.random()*horizontalMax) +'px',
                        'rotate'    : r+'deg'
                    };
                    $photo.animate(param,800);  
                });
            }

            function findHighestZIndex(){
                var photos = $container.find('.pd_photo');
                var highest = 0;
                photos.each(function(){
                    var $photo = $(this);
                    var zindex = $photo.css('z-index');
                    if (parseInt(zindex) > highest) {
                        highest = zindex;
                    }
                });
                return highest;
            }

            function findElementHighestZIndex(){
                var photos = $container.find('.pd_photo');
                var highest = 0;
                var $elem;
                photos.each(function(){
                    var $photo = $(this);
                    var zindex = $photo.css('z-index');
                    if (parseInt(zindex) > highest) {
                        highest = zindex;
                        $elem   = $photo;
                    }
                });
                return $elem;
            }

            // Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
            Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
                var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
                this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
                return this.push.apply(this, rest);
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly surplus to requirements, but include this as a stand-alone .js file on your page, and the selected elements will fade in at slightly different intervals over a period of three seconds.  Tweak to your personal preference.

```
// specify a selector for what you want to fade in
var fadeSelector = "div, span, .whatever"; 

// specify a selector for anything you don't want to fade in
// such as transparent container objects or permanent page fixtures
var noFade = "#header, #legalnotice, .transparentdiv";

$(document).ready(function()
{
   // Make all selected objects vanish objects
   $(fadeSelector).not(noFade).addClass("vanish");  
   $(".vanish").css("opacity", "0.0");

   // fade in all '.vanish' class objects'
   $(".vanish").each(function()
   {
      $(this).delay(parseInt( Math.random()*1000 + 500 )).fadeTo(parseInt( Math.random()*1000 + 500 ), 1.0);
   });
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do. Perfect. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

if im reading this right, set them as display:none in css so they're hidden and then you can fade them in at the point you need with a .fadeIn()

Answer (score 1):

Use the load() event to call a function when an image is loaded:
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

For your specific problem you will probably want to first load the images with css opacity set to zero, then count every time the load event is called and once the count is all of your images you can fade them back in.

EDIT: oh wait I see that you already have load event handlers in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

CSS:

```
#imageHolder img { display: none }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imageHolder">
<img src="image1.jpg" />
<img src="image2.jpg" />
<img src="image3.jpg" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#imageHolder img").load(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**What it does:** CSS sets all of the `<img />`s to `display: none`, which makes the invisible by default, jQuery adds an event handler for the jQuery `load` event of each image, which causes an image to `fadeIn()` when loaded.